# Como mantener un elemento de menú oculto de LocalStorage permanentemente aunque se refresque la página o se inicie una nueva sesión

Tags: javascript, html, css

Antes de nada, aclaro que se trata de una reformulación de otra pregunta.
En el menú principal de una web, se dispone de un elemento que llama a un formulario. Lo primero que se desea es ocultar o mostrar dicho elemento mediante dos botones respectivamente, que llaman a dos funciones para que realice estos cambios y para ello se utiliza el almacenamiento con localStorage. La web dispone de acceso de usuarios registrados con sus roles correspondientes. Si bien, la codificación que se expone funciona correctamente, almacenando el estado del menú mientras no se refresque la página, el problema es que si se refresca dicha pagina o se inicia sesión con otro usuario (con un rol determinado), el menú no se mantiene con los cambios. ¿ Como hacer que dichos cambios se mantengan indefinidamente aunque se refresque la página o se cambie de rol o de usuario ?.

```js
function ocultar() {
  document.getElementById('mega-menu-item-1525').style.display = 'none';
  localStorage.setItem('boton-oculto', false);
}

function mostrar() {
  document.getElementById('mega-menu-item-1525').style.display = 'block';
  localStorage.setItem('boton-oculto', true);
}

function verificar() {
  // Obtengo el valor de "boton-oculto" del localStorage.
  let oculto = localStorage.getItem('boton-oculto');
  
  // Luego verifico si "boton-oculto" está almacenado en el localStorage, si no lo está, trae "null".
  if (oculto !== null) {
    // Aquí convierto el valor de "boton-oculto" a booleano (ya que el valor viene como cadena).
    oculto = (oculto === 'true');
    console.log(oculto);
    // Y por último, dependiendo al booleano, actualizo el estado del div.
    if (oculto) {
      document.getElementById('mega-menu-item-1525').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('mega-menu-item-1525').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', verificar);
```

```css
.mega-menu-item-1525 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <button id="boton_Mostrar" onclick="mostrar();">Mostrar elemento del menú</button>
  <div id="mega-menu-item-1525">
    <button id="boton_ocultar" onclick="ocultar();">Ocultar elemento del menú</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Lo normal es que el valor lo guardemos en base de datos para mantener ese estado permanente que quieres obtener, muy bien puedes hacer desde localStorage y te puede funcionar pero puede haber el caso en el que el cliente borre los datos del naveador, cache, historial etc... y que ese efecto permanente que deseas se pierda

Comment: es tu sitio web dinámico?, es decir, se carga el html a medida que el usuario se conecta? porque si ese es el caso, es probable que el elemento con id 'mega-menu-item-1525' no exista al momento de ejecutar 'verificar', esto implica que tienes que ejecutar verificar después de que el usuario se conecte

Comment: @AlvaroJVanegas. Es una posibilidad francamente difícil, puesto que el archivo donde se guarda el estado del menú forma parte del núcleo de wordpress en concreto nav-menus.php.

Comment: @LPZadkiel. La web es estática, aunque existe un blog cuyos contenidos son escasos en tiempo y forma, además el elemento a ocultar no forma parte del blog y por lo tanto es totalmente estático.

Comment: @MAC desconocia totalmente que la web fuese estatica